# from jqgrid saving data to json or some variable on client side

Tags: jqgrid

I have a scenario I have drawn the jqgrid with data successfully, My jqgrid contains drop down, radio button, check boxes and editable cell etc. Now I change some radio button, check boxes, drop down select etc. On a button click I want to save the current grid state (after changing radio button , check boxes and click able boxes) to some variable (e.g array).

Is there any built in function, or I have to iterate over the entire table, or there is any better solution

Comment: You question is not clear enough. You wrote: "My jqgrid contains drop down, radio button, check boxes and editable cell etc". What you mean? Do you use placed HTML fragments as the data of the grid? Do you used custom formatters to place drop down, radio button, check boxes in the grid? Do you started some editing of the grid (for example inline editing of a row or multiple rows)? What do you exactly? Which `datatype` you use? The answer on your question is heavy depend on the implementation which you've chosen.

Comment: @oleg I have set the following properties
datatype: 'local',
            //pager: $("#theGridPager"),
            //viewrecords: true,
            sortname: 'value1',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
            editurl: 'clientArray',
            cellEdit: true,
And I draw grid.

Comment: Now I make changes on grid (change values). I want the updated values as well as those controls values which I didn't change. In other world I want all the data that is on grid in some variable.

Comment: Sorry, but you should *never* post information which is important for understanding of your question in the comment. Instead of that you shuld click "edit" link below of the question and modify its text. Typically one append the text with the words like **UPDATED:** or **UPDATED 1:**, **UPDATED 2:** etc and with additional information. So do you use cell editing? and the problem is to save **one cell** which is currently editing?